# difference when updating UI in dispatch_async and dispatch_sysnc

Tags: ios, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch

Let's say, I have a NSURLSession called session and I want to update my UI inside downloadTaskWithRequest. Now, What will happen in case 1 and in case 2:

**Case 1:**(dispatch_async)

```
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration];

NSURLSessionDownloadTask *task= [session downloadTaskWithRequest:request
completionHandler:^(NSURL *localFile, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error){
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    // UI Update    
                                               });
}];
```

**Case 2:** (using dispatch_sync)

```
NSURLSessionDownloadTask *task= [session downloadTaskWithRequest:request
completionHandler:^(NSURL *localFile, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error){
    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    // UI Update    
                                               });
}];
```

Comment: The second one will wait for the things inside the block to finish executing before continuing.  There isn't anything after the block in your example so there isn't really any difference.  The second will deadlock if you call it while already on the main queue though.

Comment: If you have to ask what the difference is between dispatch_async and dispatch_sync, then the answer is "use dispatch_async". For dispatch_sync, you _really_ must know what you are doing. I leave that to developers who are braver than me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr** Second case will wait for UI update finishes. First is faster.

**Deatailed**

`dispathc_sync` blocks execution on current queue until dispatched task completed. So, if something huge happens on main queue, Case two will take long time to complete. But, by the time completion handler finishes its work (if, for example, you perform something after UI update dispatch) you're sure that UI is already updated.
   Also, if by some unknown reason you'll configure `session` to dispatch completion blocks on main queue, you'll get a deadlock in second case. It is because main queue is serial, which means it executes only one tasks at a time - so completion handler will wait for UI update to complete, and UI update will not start till completion handler does not finish.

`dispatch_async` does not block execution flow. It means, that you'll not get deadlock by any means and completion block execution time will not depend on UI update duration. However, even when completion handler completed you do not know if UI update is complete.
   But, if your `completionHandler` dispatched to main queue, UI updated will execute ONLY after `completionHandler` finishes.

**Breakdown**
Case two :

```
completionHandler:^(NSURL *localFile, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error){
    //Some code
    //1
    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    //2
                    // UI Update    
                    //3
                                               });
    //Some code
    //4
}];
```

Reach `//1`, reach `//2`, reach `//3`, reach `//4`. Execution order guaranteed. No matter what - whether it goes this way or doesn't execute at all.

Case one :

```
completionHandler:^(NSURL *localFile, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error){
    //Some code
    //1
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    //2
                    // UI Update    
                    //3
                                               });
    //Some code
    //4
}];
```

Reach `//1`. Guaranteed. After that variants possible.
Reach `//2`, reach `//4`, reach `//3`.
OR
Reach `//4`, reach `//2`, reach `//3`
OR
Reach `//2`, reach `//3`, reach `//4`.

The second one will always be that way if `completionBlock` dispatched on main queue.

Feel free to ask, if something left unclear

Answer (score 1):

Note that [dispatch_get_main_queue() is a serial queue](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH102-SW3),

So whenever you dispatch a block to execute on it, it goes to the end of the line, and will execute after the processor executes all of the other tasks in front of it, in order.

when you `dispatch_async` a block (task), exactly that will happen: the task will be put at the end of the line, and the code after `dispatch_async` will continue executing.  Once the main thread finishes all the tasks in front of that dispatched task (end of run loop), your task will execute

however when you `dispatch_sync`, the current thread (in your case the main thread), will be blocked as it waits for the dispatched task to execute.  As @dan mentioned in the comments, because you are currently in the main thread, and you `dispatch_sync` a task to the main thread, you will deadlock.  This is because you added a task to the end of your main thread, while the task at the front of the line in your main thread is waiting for that last task to execute-- but it never will because it is waiting in line.

So if you want to execute a task on a separate thread, but you don't want it to happen asynchronously, you would use `dispatch_sync`.  Just make sure you never dispatch to the same thread as your current thread